# What are acceptable treatments for chronic pain that will not result in a loss of an FAA Medical?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

Is there an acceptable treatment plan for neuropathic pain? Gabapentin is not an acceptable drug. Lyrica and Cevalla aren't approved. Is there a treatment that could even get a special issuance?

Comment: Ask a doctor who is at least familiar with aviation medicine. This site has a lot of certified pilot but not as many certified doctor. Maybe if you post where you live someone maybe able to suggest a doctor for you. Get well soon :)

Comment: maybe Acupuncture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real answer here is to [consult an AME](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/amelocator/). I searched on the AOPA forums (members only) and the information wasn't encouraging: all current (as of 2014, which was the more recent relevant post I found) neuropathy drugs are disqualifying. AOPA's [list of approved drugs](http://www.aopa.org/members/databases/medical/druglist.cfm) does show some approved drugs for pain relief, but it looks like it's all OTC stuff.

But, the usual medical disclaimer applies here: every case is different so the above may be irrelevant to you personally; I'm not a doctor and I don't know what I'm talking about anyway; only an AME can give you meaningful information.